# change default browser for HTML Viewer

Tags: browser, abap

Is there a way to change the IE browser of the HTML Viewer (cl_gui_html_viewer) in abap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No with SAP GUI version <= 7.60.

- The note [738973 - HTML Viewer limitations](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/738973/E) explains that the HTML Viewer is not based on IE, but both are based on the same "OLE object "Microsoft Web Browser"".

Yes with SAP GUI version >= 7.70

- The note [2913405 - SAP GUI for Windows: Dependencies to browsers / browser controls](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2913405/E) explains that WebView2 can be used instead of the "MS Web Browser", by SAP GUI Options > Interaction Design > Control Settings > HTML Control > "Edge (based on Chromimum)" instead of "Internet Explorer".

EDIT July 2022: answer edited to consider SAP GUI 7.70

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity. What if one uses SAP GUI for Java on Linux? Theoretically it is also possible to use SAP GUI for Java on Windows, isn't it?

Comment: In the constructor of each control class, SAP determines either a ProgID for Windows or a JavaBean for Java/HTML (for the HTML Viewer, it's respectively `SAP.HTMLControl.1` and `com.sap.components.controls.htmlViewer.SapHtmlViewer`)

Comment: @Sandra Rossi thanks, is there any other way to get a control with a custom browser?

Comment: It's probably possible to embed any browser in your own Windows ActiveX control (using the programming language you want, not ABAP), but you must be familiar with that kind of development (I'm not).

Comment: This is the backup plan to program an activeX-control yourself with Visual Basic. I was looking for a solution in SAP, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those who are still wondering how to solve this problem, SAP has solved this in SAP GUI 7.70. You can switch your web view control to Edge (chromium based one) in SAP GUI 7.70.